# In Flutter go_router, how to stop pushing the same page twice when a user accidentally double-clicks the routing button at once?

Tags: flutter, routes, navigation, delay, flutter-go-router

I added a ripple effect to the custom build button when the user navigates to a new page. For the display ripple effect inside the button for a while, I delayed the user navigation to the new page by 150 milliseconds as in the code snippet below.

```dart
onTap: () {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 150), () {
      context.push("/SampleNextPage");
  });
},
```

Defining Routes

**go_router 5.0.5**

```dart
class Routes {
  final router = GoRouter(
      // initialLocation: "HomeTitlesPage",
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: "/",
          builder: (context, state) => const SplashScreen(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: "/HomePage",
          builder: (context, state) => const HomePage(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: "/SampleNextPage",
          builder: (context, state) => const SampleNextPage(),
        ),
      ], observers: [
    GoRouterObserver(),
  ]);
}
```

GoRouterObserver

```dart
class GoRouterObserver extends NavigatorObserver {
  @override
  void didPush(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    print('Pushed route: ${route.str}'); //name comes back null
    if (previousRoute != null) {
      print('previousRoute: ${previousRoute.str}');
    }
  }

  @override
  void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    print('Poped route: ${route.str}'); //name comes back null
    if (previousRoute != null) {
      print('previousRoute: ${previousRoute.str}');
    }
  }

  @override
  void didRemove(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    print('Removed route: ${route.str}'); //name comes back null
    if (previousRoute != null) {
      print('previousRoute: ${previousRoute.str}');
    }
  }

  @override
  void didReplace({Route<dynamic>? newRoute, Route<dynamic>? oldRoute}) {
    print('Replaced newRoute: ${newRoute!.str}');
    print('oldRoute: ${oldRoute!.str}'); //n//name comes back null
  }
}

extension on Route<dynamic> {
  String get str => 'route(${settings.name}: ${settings.arguments})';
}
```

In the meantime, if the user clicks the navigation button twice then the page is pushed twice to the route tree.

Accordingly, I need to preview the ripple effect and also prevent pushing the same page twice.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Btw, a true splash screen is displayed before your app has even started... What you have named SplashScreen() here should probably better be named "LoadingScreen()" or something... 

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård It's my fault. Thanks for pointing that out. As you said it is a "Loading screen". 

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to fix the issue in the wrong side. Actually, you shouldn't add that 150ms delay. I understand the ripple effect is lovely to see but that's not what the other apps do. And according to the Jakob's Law, people expect our app to work as the other apps they already know.

More info about the Jakob's Law [here](https://lawsofux.com/jakobs-law/).

Answer (score 0):

You could make the button inactive after the user has tapped it once? This would make it impossible for them to tap it a second time!... Like this:

```
  bool activeButton = true;
```

...

```
        onTap: activeButton
            ? () {
                    // This requires a StatefulWidget:
                    setState(() {
                      activeButton = false;
                    });
                    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 150), () {
                      context.push("/SampleNextPage");
                    });
                  }
            : null
```

Otherwise (like if for some reason, you want the button to remain active and tappable, but still not get more than one SampleNextPage pushed), you could write a condition before pushing. I don't know exactly how your GoRouterObserver works, but something like this:

```
        onTap: (){
                    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 150), () {
                      if (GoRouterObserver().topRoute.path != "/SampleNextPage") {
                        context.push("/SampleNextPage");
                      }
                    });
        }
```

---

Edit

Ok, I don't understand your GoRouterObserver! It doesn't seem to observe anything, to me...

When I am in a similar situation, I use a NavigationHistoryObserver! Like this:

```
import 'package:navigation_history_observer/navigation_history_observer.dart';
```

...

```
        onTap: (){
                    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 150), () {
                      if (NavigationHistoryObserver().top!.settings.name != "/SampleNextPage") {
                        context.push("/SampleNextPage");
                      }
                    });
                  }
```

Comment: I think your second solution is a good way to start solving this issue. Because in the first solution, if there a many navigation buttons on one page, we need to initialize several bool variables in UI. And what do you mean by "GoRouterObserver().topRoute". My GoRouterObserver is as below.

Comment: I said I didn't know exactly how your GoRouterObserver worked... ".topRoute" was just a chance-taking, knowing you would understand what I meant!  But plz don't put code in a comment! If you really need me to update my answer with your GoRouterObserver, plz edit it into your question.

Comment: I got it . Yes, I will do it that way.

Comment: Answer edited. 